# Laravel unit test always error with code 401

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm making unit tests using laravel, I have 50 tests. but when a test that requires auth, the test automatically fails and raises a 401 error

```
  Expected status code 404 but received 401. Failed asserting that 404 is identical to 401.
```

for the failed test, like this is the code. I use actingAs to work around auth, but it always fails

```
 public function testDenyNonAdminUserAccess()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $author = factory(Author::class)->create();

        $response = $this
            ->actingAs($user)
            ->postJson('/api/books', [
                'isbn' => '9788328302341',
                'title' => 'Clean code',
                'description' => 'Lorem ipsum',
                'authors' => [$author->id],
            ]);

        $response->assertStatus(403);
    }
```

even though when I use postman to insert data, it always works and there are no problems. is there any solution?

I also put the middleware in the controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth:api', 'auth.admin'])->except('index');
    }
```

is there any solution?

Comment: Remove auth.admin and try

Comment: @Savlon still error

Comment: I've tried it, and still error 401

Comment: Try Passport::actingAs($user);

Answer (score 0):

To me, It seems there is no user in your memory database.
Try this one to check whether there are users saved in your DB or not.

```
User::factory(10)->create();
$this->assertEquals(10, User::get()->count());
```

If it is, try to login a specific user like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$this->actingAs($user);
```